# Derivation of some property of the Dirac delta function

Tags: integration, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

I have some question about the property of the delta function:
$$
\int g(x)\delta(f(x))dx=\frac{g(0)}{|f'(0)|}.
$$
I know how to derive this identity, but what I am not so sure is why there is the absolute value in the denominator. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?